Motor sensorless Control with STM32
I would kindly need the feedback of someone who has used stm32 and MC Workbench software.
I'm driving a BLDC motor (14 poles) with stm32 MC Workbench (using Motor Pilot tool) and I connect it to STM32 B-G431B-ESC1 inverter. I am using a sensorless control (PLL + Observer).
Before writing any instructions in the main I would like to plot the speed and possibly the current to make sure they are consistent with those set.
Once the project was generated, I set these parameters for sensorless start-up:

In the main.c I did not write anything because the initialization function MX_MotorControl_Init() is written by the software (when you generate the project).
When a button is pressed on B-G431B-ESC1, the startup phase MC_StartMotor1() begins.
With stm32 monitor I plotted the average and reference mechanical speed:

The plotted variables return on the y-axis the last computed average (or reference) mechanical rotor speed, expressed in #SPEED_UNIT = speed*U_RPM/SPEED_UNIT = speed * 60/10.
I have no idea how to interpret this graph, neither the time base (x-axis) nor the velocity (y-axis) match the start-up parameters set in the first picture.
